# Calling << operator on types held in a std::variant?

Tags: c++, variant, visitor-pattern

I've got a struct like this:

```
// Literal.hpp
struct Literal
{
    std::variant<
        std::nullptr_t,
        std::string,
        double,
        bool
        >
        value;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Literal &literal);
};
```

and I'm trying to implement the << operator like this:

```
// Literal.cpp
Literal::Literal() : value(value) {}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Literal &literal)
{
    std::visit(/* I don't know what to put here!*/, literal.value);
}
```

I've tried implementing the operator like this (note: I would take any elegant solution it doesn't have to be a solution to this implementation below)

```
// In Literal.cpp
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Literal literal)
{
    std::visit(ToString(), literal.value);
    return out;
}

struct ToString; // this declaration is in literal.hpp

void ToString::operator()(const std::nullptr_t &literalValue){std::cout << "null";}
void ToString::operator()(const char &literalValue){std::cout << std::string(literalValue);}
void ToString::operator()(const std::string &literalValue){std::cout << literalValue;}
void ToString::operator()(const double &literalValue){std::cout << literalValue;}
void ToString::operator()(const bool &literalValue){std::cout << literalValue;}
```

But in my main function, passing a char array literal doesn't casts it into a bool when it runs! ignoring the operator overload taking a char:

```
main() {
    Literal myLiteral;
    myLiteral.value = "Hello World";
    std::cout << myLiteral << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in your standard library. Presumably you're using libstc++ (the GNU C++ standard library), since that's what Godbolt shows as messing up. If you compile with libc++ (Clang/LLVM's C++ standard library), this works as expected. According to [`std::vector<Types...>::operator=(T&& t)`'s cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator%3D), it

> Determines the alternative type `T_j` that would be selected by overload resolution for the expression `F(std::forward<T>(t))` if there was an overload of imaginary function `F(T_i)` for every `T_i` from Types... in scope at the same time, except that:
>
> - An overload `F(T_i)` is only considered if the declaration `T_i x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };` is valid for some invented variable `x`;
> - If `T_i` is (possibly cv-qualified) `bool`, `F(T_i)` is only considered if `std:remove_cvref_t<T>` is also `bool`.

That last clause is there for this very situation. Because lots of things can convert to `bool`, but we don't usually intend this conversion, that clause causes conversion sequences that would not normally be selected to be selected (`char const*` to `bool` is a standard conversion, but to `std::string` is "user-defined", which is normally considered "worse"). Your code *should* set `value` to its `std::string` alternative, but your library's implementation of `std::variant` is broken. There's probably an issue ticket already opened, but if there isn't, this is grounds to open one. If you're stuck with your library, explicitly marking the literal as a `std::string` should work:

```
literal.value = std::string("Hello World");
```

---

For the elegance question, use an abbreviated template lambda.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Literal const &literal)
{
    std::visit([](auto v) { std::cout << v; }, literal.value);
    // or
    std::visit([](auto const &v) {
        // gets template param      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv w/o being able to name it
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>, std::nullptr_t>) {
           std::cout << "null";
        } else std::cout << v;
    }, literal.value);
    // only difference is nullptr_t => "nullptr" vs "null"

    return std::cout;
}
```

Also, your `friend` declaration doesn't match the definition. Actually, it shouldn't be `friend`ed anyway, since it needs no access to `private` members.

```
// declaration in header, outside of any class, as a free function
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, Literal const&);
//                            was missing const ^^^^^
```

Comment: FWIW, I seem to remember that `bool` exception coming later in a separate paper, so it's quite possible the implementation simply hasn't implemented that paper on top of its old support yet. (And since it changes the behaviour of existing code, I can see how that might be a deliberately delayed decision.) (Ah, it's linked on the page: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html)

Comment: @chris Thanks for finding that. I checked eel.is to doublecheck what the standard said but apparently that's not in there yet.

Comment: I am using clang++. My build task is clang++ -g *.cpp -o main -std=c++17. 

clang++ --version gives apple clang 11 (clang-1100.0.33.17)

Comment: casting the char to string manually does work, but I wanted to see if I could just fix my current implementation. I'll check your lambda function method see if it works

Comment: I suppose Apple clang is a bit behind. I'm testing the actual LLVM Clang 10.0.0 on godbolt.org (*with `-stdlib=libc++`*, because for some god-forsaken reason it defaults to GNU `libstdc++`).

Comment: Yeah your lambda function fails on my compiler, it says multiple valid << overloads for literal.value.

Is there a way I can update my compiler? Or download a new version of clang++? I'm new to c++ development. I tried building clang++ once but i couldn't even find the resulting binary, let alone know how to replace my current binary with it. Hopefully there's a straightforward way

Comment: I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), so I just `brew install llvm` and then add `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin` to my `PATH`. `brew` is a bit funky with permissions though, so you may not want to use it. If you go the [LLVM page](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html), they have macOS binaries. Looking at the contents, it appears that you can just unpack it into any directory and then add `<that_directory>/bin` to your `PATH` and be done with it. (Homebrew would essentially place it in `/usr/local/opt/llvm`, but you can e.g. put it somewhere in your home directory.)

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I can mark your answer as accepted once I'm able to test it out in an updated environment