# How can I print map key/value with std::variant?

Tags: c++, dictionary, variant

I'm trying to print the key of a certain value in my dictionary. I defined my map like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::variant<float,int,bool,std::string>> kwargs; 
kwargs["interface"] = "probe"; 
kwargs["flag"] = true; 
kwargs["Height"] = 5; 
kwargs["length"] = 6;
```

I tried to print the value normally but a (no operator "<<" matches these operands) error occurs.

```
std::cout << kwargs["flag"] << std::endl;
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: FYI: `std::endl` is usually unnecessary. `"\n"` works fine, is just as portable, and is often faster. Use `std::endl` (which is equivalent to `"\n"` followed by `std::flush`) only when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) with a generic lambda that prints any type to `std::cout`, as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, std::variant<float,int,bool,std::string>> kwargs; 
kwargs["interface"] = "probe"s;
kwargs["flag"] = true; 
kwargs["Height"] = 5; 
kwargs["length"] = 6; 

for (const auto& [k, v] : kwargs){
    std::cout << k << " : ";
    std::visit([](const auto& x){ std::cout << x; }, v);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This works because all of `float`, `int`, `bool`, and `std::string` have overloads for the output stream operator `<<`. For other types, or to override this behaviour, you could use a custom functor class instead of a lambda:

```
struct PrintVisitor {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(const T& t) const {
        std::cout << t;
    }

    // prints std::string in quotes
    void operator(const std::string& s) const {
        std::cout << '\"' << s << '\"';
    }
};

[...]

std::visit(PrintVisitor{}, kwargs);
```

**NOTE**: unfortunately, the line `kwargs["interface"] = "probe";` doesn't actually select the `std::string` constructor for the variant type, because the string literal preferentially converts to a `bool` rather than a `std::string` ([further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770252/string-literal-matches-bool-overload-instead-of-stdstring)). You can avoid this by explicitly making a `std::string` using, for example, `std::string{"probe"}` or the standard `std::string` user-defined literal, as in `"probe"s`.

[Live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fc25ec092fd3f4f)

Comment: [That last bit has very recently changed, in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61298916/5684257). It's not implemented yet in some standard libraries, but eventually that line will work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can define `operator<<` for your type:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::variant<float,int,bool,std::string> const& v) {
    std::visit([&os](auto const& x) { os << x; }, v);
    return os;
}
```

You can generalize the solution to work with any `variant` specialization:

```
template <class Var, class = std::variant_alternative_t<0, Var>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Var const& v) {
    std::visit([&os](auto const& x) { os << x; }, v);
    return os;
}
```

Note, the second template parameter exists to disable the definition if the `Var` is not a `std::variant` specialization.

Comment: Yes, `visit` is clearly the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `operator<<` for `std::variant`, which can't be printed out directly. You need to read the value from the variant (by index or type), e.g.

```
std::cout << std::get<bool>(kwargs["flag"]) << std::endl;
```

Or

```
std::cout << std::get<2>(kwargs["flag"]) << std::endl;
```

Comment: It works for bool and int type but for string and float I get an error

Comment: @Miléna In your code you're not assigning `float`. It should work fine with `std::string`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/al0lzifbjwuf6nqf

Comment: weird I'm running my code on visual studio 2019 and an error occurs for strings and float